# When a web site asks for my "PayPal account", is it just the email address I use with PayPal?

Tags: ecommerce, paypal

I just created a PayPal account because I want to get registered on a web site requiring PayPal. In the registration form on that site there is one field to be filled in: "PayPal account", but I don't really know what exactly I am supposed to type in there. Should it be my email address that I gave PayPal while I was registering there (letters from PayPal come to this e-mail box of mine), or should it be something else?

Comment: @duffbeer703 I think this question is fine.  It's more a "money" question than a "finance" one.  But, questions about online payment systems like PayPal, which can be used by individuals, are on-topic.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea: Thank You very much for editing my question. I just didn't know how to put it into words properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your email address is your "PayPal" account. It's what people use to send you money, and what you use to pay people.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you intend to buy things from that website, that website has no business asking for 'your paypal account'.

Either they've got malicious intent, or they just want an email address and are painfully unaware of how infosec works and in either case I would not recommend giving them *anything* pertaining to your financial information.

Comment: Actually, the only valid reason for asking for "your PayPal account" is if they want to send money TO you. If they want you to pay for something, they should instead redirect you to the PayPal website to sign in and confirm the payment there. The whole point of PayPal is that (unlike card payments) the merchant never sees your payment credentials at all.

Answer (score 0):

Id meber
2
Yes, your email address is your "PayPal" account. It's what people use to send you money, and what you use to pay people.